# MS Word changes number list font upon download

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

When I download a Word document from the web, the number list changes font. I am using Roboto, and my template on Speclink is in Roboto. I download a Word document from Speclink, and when I open it up the number list font is in Times New Roman.

To change the font to Roboto, I have to File/Options/Advanced/Font Substitution and change it to Roboto for every document. I have clicked Change Permanently, and updated my Normal.dotm template. When I File/Options/Advanced/Font Substitution in my Normal.dotm template, it will not update, I get a message that all of the fonts have already been substituted.